# google map view version 2 in activity group

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello I have tab based application containing activity groups . In one activitygroup i have a sub activity  , in which I have to display a map and plot multiple location which i am getting as a response from the server , As google map  version 1 is no more supported I have to use 
oogle map  version 2 but when ever I use this xml given below I get the xml inflate  Infalte that Fragments

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teks.googlemaps/com.teks.googlemaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

```
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                        <fragment
                            android:id="@+id/map"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"

                            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>
```

To add more specification I HAVE added the google play services . made the api key and my target device in android 2.2

plz help

Comment: i have change the taget api from android 2.2 to google api 4.03 but still not working

Comment: show your java class file code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FragmentActivity for SupportMapFragment to work.

Btw. ActivityGroup is deprecated for more than 2 years now.